# How to create rounded rectangle in css using percentage

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rectangle using HTML and CSS, like this.

[image]

Is there a way to get the rounded rectangle illustrated in the above picture (left and right parts should look like a semi-circle) without knowing the exact width and height of the button/div?

Using `border-radius: 50%` will result in an oval. The main problem is  I don't know the exact dimension of the rectangle.

**Update**:

As @Deykun said, I can use sufficiently large fixed value for border-radius.

Comment: I dont get the desired outcome / your particular issue

Comment: border-radius: calc(20%/10%);

Comment: Your question is not clear, please give more details or try to explain it in another way.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the button from the image you don't need percentages at all. You can use `border-radius: 30px;` and it will create even rounding by default. Buttons smaller than 60px in height will divide height in half for example button with `height: 40px;` will look the same with `border-radius: 30px;` and `border-radius: 20px;` and they will behave differently for buttons higher than 40px.

But you can use `border-top-left-radius: 10% 100px;` to create uneven rounding.

```css
button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  
  border: none;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<button>Short</button>

<button>Long button</button>

<button>+</button>
```

Comment: hmm, so I can use sufficiently large number in border-radius, I was hoping there would be a much better solution

Answer (score -1):

`border-radius : 50px;` will give you the desired rounded radius like the attached image.